# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I am doing the building an OpenGL environment from android studio but i encountered this cannot resolve symbol. I am not sure why. I originally have this issue on `gLView` but i was able to get that taken care of with importing `android.opengl.GLSurfaceView` but as i am understanding it `MyGLSurfaceView` is a new class? but its being called from `GLSurfaceView` via `gLView`? im a little confused on why this is happening and what i did wrong.

```
package com.example.opengltest;

import android.app..Activity;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;



import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private GLSurfaceView gLView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as  the Content View for this Activity
    gLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(gLView);
}
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.opengltest">
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Beyond that: simply put the error message into a search engine. "cannot resolve symbol" is a very basic error, and there plenty of good questions explaining the various potential causes.

Comment: At least tell us which variable it is complaining about...

Comment: 'MyGLSurfaceView(this)'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,let me know what happens.

```
gLView = findViewById(R.id.myview); //Try with this line ,initialize (myview is example id) 

    gLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(gLView);
```

XML add this line to your layout file

```
android:id="@+id/myview"
```

Comment: Can you share your .xml file to,because myview is example of id.

Comment: i edited it to show the XML code sorry if i am doing something wrong on here not fully sure how to use this place

Comment: It s ok,you uploaded manifest,can you go to your Layout folder and copy code from there.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: IT wouldn't let me edit it for some reason and kept saying that it was an error when there was no error